# Models folder is missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

something happened after uploading my asp.net mvc project on the web. when I opened my project in visual studio after the uploading to make some changes the Models folder was missing. I can see the model classess from Class View option but I can't find the Models folder in solution explorer. I'll appreciate your help

Comment: Is the models folder there when you browse for it in windows explorer? Just drag and drop it into your solution explorer.

Answer (score 5):

Solution Explorer has a *Show All Files* button. That will display items under the project folder but not tracked by Visual Studio.

[image]

Right-click the *Models* folder and **Include In Project**.